# How do i randomize starting point of tensorflow dataset pipeline

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm building a tf.data input pipeline for timeseries.
I'd like to start each epoch at a random index within the dataset.
I can't get that to work though.

Here's what I tried with a function called random_start():

```
def random_start(dataset):
  dataset = dataset[tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=1, maxval=5, dtype=tf.int32):]
  return dataset

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_data)

dataset = (
    dataset
    .map(random_start)
    # these operations can be ignored for this question:
    .batch(self.data_details.seq_length+1, drop_remainder=True)
    .map(split_input_target)
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
    .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE, reshuffle_each_iteration=True))
```

when I do

```
dataset.as_numpy_iterator.next()
```

I get that it has nothing to return.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue I see is that you are trying to use map when you should be using apply. [Map](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) takes each element in a dataset and returns a new element, whereas [apply](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#apply) takes the entire dataset and returns a new dataset.

You can try to use [skip](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#skip) in the apply function, however getting this to skip a random amount each time will be very tricky.

Instead, for your use-case, I would recommend using [window](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#window). E.g:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)

sequence_size = 4
dataset = dataset.window(sequence_size, shift=1)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(sequence_size, drop_remainder=True))

for sample in iter(dataset): 
  print(sample.numpy())
```

Output:

```py
[0 1 2 3]
[1 2 3 4]
[2 3 4 5]
[3 4 5 6]
[4 5 6 7]
[5 6 7 8]
[6 7 8 9]
```